# Как удалять zip файл с сервера?

Tags: php

Привет всем подскажите как удалять zip rar файлы из сервера ??

Использую такой код удалят все кроме zip rar

```
if (!isset($_GET['remove'])) die('Не задан файл для удаления');
if (@unlink("archiv/".$_GET['remove']))
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Для начала уберите @ перед unlink, возможно, после этого, появится решение.

Answer (score -1):

Удалите zip-файл с вашего сервера, используя unlink("path/file")

Примечание. В качестве меры предосторожности может быть разумным, чтобы скрипт PHP выполнялся автоматически (обычно - crontab), который удалял старые zip-файлы во временном каталоге.

Это на случай, если ваш обычный PHP-скрипт иногда прерывается и не удаляет временный файл.

Comment: А в первом посту в вопросе разве не unlink() указана?

Comment: @lvl там указан `@unlink`

Comment: И чем `unlink()` отличается от `@unlink()`? P.S. И не надо отвечать: что собачкой.

Comment: @Visman **@** подавляет сообщения об ошибках, поэтому если unlink дал ошибку (например, путь не существует, или нет разрешения на удаление), **@unlink** скажет PHP, чтобы не показывать ошибку. В общем случае считается неправильной формой использования **@**, потому что, если вы ожидаете, что может произойти ошибка, вы должны выполнить правильные проверки условий ошибки.